# Not getting Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Max-Age with flask-cors

Tags: python, flask, flask-cors

code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
import json
from flask_cors import CORS
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/app/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000",
                                 "allow_headers": ["Origin", "Authorization", "X-Frame-Options", "X-Requested-With", "DNT", "User-Agent", "If-Modified-Since", "Cache-Control", "Range", "X-Real-IP", "HOST", "X-NginX-Proxy", "Content-Type", "If-Match"],
                                 "expose_headers": ["ETag", "Content-Length", "Content-Range", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
                                 "max_age": "3600"}})


@app.route('/app/compute', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def compute():
    input = request.json
    responsedict = dict()
    responsedict['customerid'] = 'customer A'
    responsedict['loan_amount'] = 0
    return Response(json.dumps(responsedict), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

serve(app, port=5000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

requirements.txt is as follows:

```
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
waitress==2.1.1
```

I am not getting following headers in response of Options request: Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Max-Age

[image: postman screenshot showing missing headers]

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the extension's code:

```
    # This is a preflight request
    # http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests
    if request_method == 'OPTIONS':
        acl_request_method = request_headers.get(ACL_REQUEST_METHOD, '').upper()

        # If there is no Access-Control-Request-Method header or if parsing
        # failed, do not set any additional headers
        if acl_request_method and acl_request_method in options.get('methods'):

            # If method is not a case-sensitive match for any of the values in
            # list of methods do not set any additional headers and terminate
            # this set of steps.
            headers[ACL_ALLOW_HEADERS] = get_allow_headers(options, request_headers.get(ACL_REQUEST_HEADERS))
            headers[ACL_MAX_AGE] = options.get('max_age')
            headers[ACL_METHODS] = options.get('methods')
        else:
            LOG.info("The request's Access-Control-Request-Method header does not match allowed methods. CORS headers will not be applied.")
```

So you need to send an OPTIONS request, and have the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header. And for getting the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header in response, you need the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in your request.

This request will work:

```
curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute2' -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST"
```

sample response:

```
[ilias@yellowhat ~] > curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute' -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: post"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> OPTIONS /app/compute HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: post
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Werkzeug/2.1.1 Python/3.10.4
< Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2022 14:18:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Allow: POST, GET, HEAD, PUT, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Length, Content-Range, ETag
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 4444
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[ilias@yellowhat ~] >
```

for 2nd header as well:

```
curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute' -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: get" -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control'
```

response:

```
[ilias@yellowhat flask_cors] > curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute' -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: get" -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> OPTIONS /app/compute HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: get
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Werkzeug/2.1.1 Python/3.10.4
< Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2022 14:35:26 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Allow: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Length, Content-Range, ETag
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, If-Modified-Since
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 4444
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[ilias@yellowhat flask_cors] >
```

these requests will not work:

```
curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute' -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: somethinghere"
curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute' -X OPTIONS
curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8000/app/compute' -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST"
```